# scheduler which runs for every 1 minute. What if the task inside a scheduler takes 10 minutes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using firebase pub/sub scheduler in nodejs.
I have a scheduler which runs for every 1 minute. What if the task inside a scheduler takes 10 minutes to complete and before 10 minutes if another instance of scheduler starts again then what will happen to the already existing scheduler instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud function instances are independent of each other. The previous one will keep running and processing what it was.

Cloud functions can run up to a max duration of [9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) (10 minutes for [2nd gen](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/overview)) so do checkout if that's suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to phrase what @Dharmaraj said: The scheduler just publishes a message every minute. Each job triggered by such a message then runs for its 10 minutes (independently).